# Function doesn't return expected value and printf doesn't return any value

Tags: c, string, debugging, encryption, printf-debugging

Hi I am new to C but not to programming(Only have experience in high-level languages like Python and JS).

In my CS assignment I have to implement a function that decodes an encrypted string.(The encryption used is atbash)

I want to give the decode-function a encoded string and receive a decoded string.
I tested my function by printing out every decoded character of the string and it worked.

However I am having issues implementing the original task of the function (encoded str -> decoded str)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*******************/
// atbash decoding function
// recieves an atbash string and returns a decoded string.
char *decode(char *str){

  int i = 0;
  char decodedString[1000];
  strcpy(decodedString, "\n");

  while(str[i] != '\0') {

    if(!((str[i] >= 0 && str[i] < 65)||(str[i] > 90 && str[i] < 97)||(str[i] > 122 && str[i] <=127))){

        if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
          char upperCaseLetter = 'Z'+'A'-str[i];
          strcat(decodedString, &upperCaseLetter);
        }

        if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){
          char lowerCaseLetter = 'z'+'a'-str[i];
          strcat(decodedString, &lowerCaseLetter);
        }
      }

    if(((str[i] >= 0&& str[i] < 65)||(str[i] > 90 && str[i] < 97)||(str[i] > 122 && str[i] <= 127))){
      char notALetter = str[i];
      strcat(decodedString, &notALetter);
    }
   i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", decodedString); // Debug: Checking what I would receive as a return, expected "Hello World!", got binaries
  return decodedString;
}

int main(){


  char *message = "Svool Dliow!";

  printf("This is the decode String:\n%s",(decode(message))); //Expected return of "This is the decode String:\nHello World!", received "This is the decode String:\n" instead



  return 0;
}
```

Issues:

(1)

I receive in the debug comment some binaries, instead of a string ("Hello World!").

(2)

I don't understand why 
printf("\n%s", (decoded(message))); doesn't print the callback of function decode ._.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Issue (2) was solved thanks to paulsm4

**Edit2:**

Issue (1) was solved thanks to dbush.

Comment: PROBLEM: You cannot allocate `char decodedString[1000];` *INSIDE* of your function.  That storage ([stack storage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/)) becomes *INVALID* once the function exits.

Comment: You need to review memory allocation topics in C - memory allocated inside a function (like `decodedString` in `decode`) will be released when the call to the function ends.  You are referencing de-allocated memory.

Comment: Both arguments to `strcat` should be a pointer to a null-terminated string, not a pointer to a single character.

Comment: @dbush Could you please give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: `strcat(decodedString, &upperCaseLetter);` is invalid because the second argument is not a string.

Comment: @dbush I understand. Can you recommend any solution to fix this? Or is there any other way I can concat single chars to a string in C?

Comment: Keep track of the number of characters in the string and copy each character to the current end position, then at the end add a terminating null byte to make it a string.

Comment: `strcat(decodedString, (char[2]){upperCaseLetter});` is an not so efficient solution to append.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering! I figured out that strcat was misplaced in my code and figured an easy solution and everything works as planned. Thanks again for your patience :)